# FormView, inserting null programmatically in OnItemInserting or OnItemUpdating event

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, formview

I am using FormView control, and I want to programmatically insert null value in OnItemInserting and OnItemUpdating event, by NewValues dictioanry in FormViewUpdateEventArgs parameter. But if I use

```
protected void FormView_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues["EntityFrameworkEntityPropertyName"] = null;
}
```

such modification is ignored, database column is not updated and keeps its old value. EntityFramework entity property is: Type Int32, Nullable True, StoreGeneratedPattern None.

If I bind TextBox control directly to property by Bind(), nulls are inserted well. Also if values are different from null, everything works fine.

How can I insert null value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. `DetailsView` and `FormView` in `OnItemUpdating` event compares previous and new values and if these are changed, update it. When I put null into `e.NewValues`, while my `TextBox` is not bounded by `Bound` function, `e.OldValues["EntityFrameworkEntityPropertyName"]` doesn't exists (means null) and in `NewValues` is null also, so column is not updated.

I simply set `e.OldValues["EntityFrameworkEntityPropertyName"]` to anything (but same type) and now inserting nulls works fine.

```
protected void FormView_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.OldValues["EntityFrameworkEntityPropertyName"] = -1
    e.NewValues["EntityFrameworkEntityPropertyName"] = null;
}
```

My textbox is not bounded directly, because I need to process its value before I will show it up to user. On insert/update I need also some value processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
  e.NewValues["EntityFrameworkEntityPropertyName"] = System.DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: This raises exception DBNull can not be converted to Int32 nillable (by entity framework).